# how to pass a queue to another function in c

Tags: c

I am trying to pass a queue to another function in c in order to make some operations on it, I've tried to send it's reference and put in a pointer in the function arguments but that doesn't make sense!

here's what I did:

this is the caller:

```
G = my_job(&qu, inducing_cell, target_cell, G, vertices_number, cells_number);
```

this is the function:

```
graph* my_job(Queue *qu, Position inducing_cell, Position target_cell, graph* G, unsigned long vertices_number, unsigned long cells_number) {}
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit please? There's nothing inherently wrong with your example code, so what doesn't make sense?

Comment: There is no question in your posting, please add one.

Comment: If passing pointer to queue, doesn't make sense, then what does - i wonder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the address of a variable to a `Queue` struct.

So as follows:

```
 Queue q; //create a queue instance
 G =  my_job(&q /*Pass in address to Q*/, inducing_cell, target_cell, G, vertices_number, cells_number);
```

Or you can create a pointer to a `Queue` and pass that in:

```
 Queue* q = malloc(sizeof(Queue)); //Make sure you have allocated the pointer (unless my_job allocates it inside)
 G = my_job(q /*Pass in pointer (pointer is copied)*/, inducing_cell, target_cell, G, vertices_number, cells_number);
 //Do stuff with q
 free(q); // Free the memory.
```

If you want to pass in a pointer to alter what it points to and see the changes when the function returns, you'll need to pass in a `Queue**` because a pointer is passed by value, ie it's copied into the function.  So if you change what it points to inside, that change is not seen when the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give some detail on what kind of operations you are doing. Is qu a variable or a pointer?

If qu is a pointer, than you need to pass just the pointer, not the address of it. However, if you want to modify the pointer itself in the function, the function parameter must be `Queue** que`, and you need to pass the address of the qu to the function. Defining this as a simple rule in C; if you want to modify a variable in a function, you need to pass the address of the variable to the function.